# Improper integral and the ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals

How does one calculate a derivative from improper integral like this?

$$\int_t^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x-t)}{x}dx\qquad\ $$

It's been said that this particular integral (as a function) satisfies the equation

$$y''+y=\frac{1}{t},\qquad t>0$$

but I just can't see how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an application of the Leibniz theorem: derivation under the sign $\int$

First by an obvious change of variable we see that this integral is equal to
$$y(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x+t}dx$$
so let $h(t,x)=\frac{\sin x}{x+t}$ then we have
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}(t,x)=-\frac{\sin x}{(x+t)^2}$$
and

$$\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial t^2}(t,x)=2\frac{\sin x}{(x+t)^3}$$
and we have
$$\left|\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}(t,x)\right|\le\frac{1}{(x+a)^2}\in L^1([a,+\infty[),\;\forall a>0$$
and $$\left|\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial t^2}(t,x)\right|\le\frac{2}{(x+a)^3}\in L^1([a,+\infty[),\;\forall a>0$$
hence $y$ is twice differentiable on $(0,+\infty)$ (in fact $C^\infty(0,+\infty)$) and
$$y''(t)=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{(x+t)^3}dx$$

Now from the expression of $y$ we integrate  by parts and we find
$$y=-\frac{\cos x}{t+x}\bigg|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{(t+x)^2}dx=\frac1t-\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{(t+x)^2}dx$$
and by a second integration by parts we recognize the expression of $y''$ and we  find easily that
$$y''+y=\frac1t$$

Comment: Ok, I encountered a dead end again (or I'm doing something wrong). What about $f(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-tx}}{1+x^2}dx$ ? The above-mentioned differential equation is supposedly satisfied as well.

Comment: I prefer that you post this in a new question in order to profit all the readers:-)