# Improper integral and the ordinary differential equation 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals

How to prove that

$$f(t)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-tx}}{1+x^2}dx$$

satisfies

$$f''(t)+f(t)=\frac1t ?$$

Comment: Are you sure it's not $f(t)$ instead of $f(x)$? The integral has as parameter $t$.

Comment: Absolutely, my mistake.

Comment: What have you tried?  As a hint, under some circumstances, you can pull a derivative inside of an integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the same method used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717025/improper-integral-and-the-ordinary-differential-equation/717054#717054):

Let $$h(t,x)=\frac{e^{-tx}}{1+x^2}$$
then
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}(t,x)=-\frac{xe^{-tx}}{1+x^2}$$
and

$$\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial t^2}(t,x)=\frac{x^2e^{-tx}}{1+x^2}$$
and we have
$$\left|\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}(t,x)\right|\le\frac{xe^{-ax}}{1+x^2}\in L^1([a,+\infty)),\;\forall a>0$$
and
$$\left|\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial t^2}(t,x)\right|\le\frac{x^2e^{-ax}}{1+x^2}\in L^1([a,+\infty)),\;\forall a>0$$
hence $y$ is twice differentiable on $(0,+\infty)$ (in fact $C^\infty(0,+\infty)$) and
$$y''(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2e^{-tx}}{1+x^2}dx$$

Now from this expression of $y''$ we write
$$y''(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2e^{-tx}}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{(x^2+1-1)e^{-tx}}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty{e^{-tx}}dx-y\\=-\frac1te^{-tx}\bigg|_0^\infty-y=\frac1t-y$$
so we conclude
$$y''+y=\frac1t$$

Comment: I got $f''(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2e^{-tx}}{1+x^2}dx$, but didn't know how to make $\frac1t + something$ from it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome:-)